# Backbone + RequireJS + jQuery: $(window).load() not working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, onload

I'm putting the following inside my Backbone Main View's initialize section:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    console.log('Page Loaded');
});

$(window).unload(function() {
    console.log('Page Unloaded');
});
```

`Page Unloaded` will be displayed on Unload event properly however 
`Page Loaded` never shows up. Changing the bit of code into the following works:

```
$(function() {
    console.log('Page Loaded');
});
```

But I need `$(window).load()`. Any idea on why and how?

Comment: `$(function() {` is a shorthand for `$(document).ready();`. Mind sharing the page with us? Apparently there has to be an error there or your downloading huge files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(fn)` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(fn)`, which isn't the same as `$(window).load(fn)`.

Perhaps window's onload has already fired when you bind this event? This isn't a problem with document ready because jQuery has some special handling to run it immediately if it already happened.

Comment: I think you are right that the `onload` event has already happened by the time the binding was executed. Thanks =)